# Got error when I want to take the ImageView from layout and set the image

Tags: android

Hi have an anroid application and I want take the ImageView from layout and set the image But I got the error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`
I try log and It will show the uri,and  `imageResource is also 0`

ps: the value of Log for `building.getImage()` is `church` however, I have `church.png` in my drawable folder

I will appreciate if you could help
Here is the code:

```
/* Extract the Building's object to show */
        Buildings building = (Buildings) getItem(position);
        ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageCity);

            String uri = "drawable/" + building.getImage();
            int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(building.getImage(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            Log.e("URI", uri);
            Log.e("context.getPackag", context.getPackageName());
            Log.e("imageResource", String.valueOf(imageResource));

            Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, imageResource);
            imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

the first parameter of `getIdentifier` is the name of the resource, whose id you are looking for, without extension. In your case this is  `building.getImage()` and not `uri`, which is the concatenation of "drawable/" and the image's name. The fact the you want to look for it inside drawable, is specified in the second parameter of getIdentifier. Change from

```
int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

to

```
int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(building.getImage(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks But Still got the same error and imagerecource is 0

Comment: what's the vale of `building.getImage()`? Do you have it in on the `drawable-*/` folder ?

Comment: it's image and yes I have it I use log and it will show the name of image in this case "church" But without extention .png should I add it in uri?

Comment: to sum it up. `building.getImage()` returns `"church"`, you have a `church.png` in one of your drawable folders and you changed your code in order to reflect the changes I suggested. Am I correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90507/discussion-between-lili-and-blackbelt).

Comment: is the value of imageResource always 0 ? –

Comment: it is 0 for every image? Are you that `building.getImage()` is not  returning a String with spaces before or after ?

Comment: E/building.getImage()﹕ church  there is a space bfore

Comment: that's the problem, try with `building.getImage().trim()`

Comment: still there is space @ Blackbelt

Comment: why don't you remove the space while you are constructing `Buildings`?